# Custom batch handler in asp.net webapi

Tags: api, batch-file, handler

I want to write custom batch handler in my webapi.

Requirement for this : I am not able to identify weather the incoming request is part of batch or independent.

By writing custom batch handler i will be able to add value in header of each request, which i can use later to identify.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to  write custom batch hahttps://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ndler
For this we need to override **HttpMessageHandler**. Below is code

```
public class BatchHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    HttpMessageInvoker _server;

    public BatchHandler(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // BatchServer is a class which overrides 
        _server = new HttpMessageInvoker(new BatchServer(config));
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Return 400 for the wrong MIME type
        // As batch request will always be of MIME type
        if ("multipart/mixed" !=
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType)
        {
            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        // Start a multipart response 
        var outerContent = new MultipartContent("batch");
        var outerResp = request.CreateResponse();
        outerResp.Content = outerContent;

        // Read the multipart request
        var multipart = await request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

        foreach (var httpContent in multipart.Contents)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage innerResp = null;

            try
            {
                // Decode the request object
                var innerReq = await
                    httpContent.ReadAsHttpRequestMessageAsync();

                innerReq.Headers.Add("IsBatch", "true");

                // Send the request through the pipeline
                innerResp = await _server.SendAsync(
                    innerReq,
                    cancellationToken
                );

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // If exceptions are thrown, send back generic 400
                innerResp = new HttpResponseMessage(
                    HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                );
            }

            // Wrap the response in a message content and put it
            // into the multipart response
            outerContent.Add(new HttpMessageContent(innerResp));
        }

        return outerResp;
    }
}
```

in above code their is this line

```
// BatchServer is a class which overrides HttpServer
_server = new HttpMessageInvoker(new BatchServer(config));
```

if we don't do this we gets an error

> The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property
>   'InnerHandler' of 'xxhandler' is not null.\r\nParameter
>   name: handlers

Below is the BatchServer class which overrides HttpServer

```
public class BatchServer : HttpServer
{
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _config;

    public BatchServer(HttpConfiguration configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
        _config = configuration;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        var firstInPipeline = _config.MessageHandlers.FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstInPipeline != null && firstInPipeline.InnerHandler != null)
        {
            InnerHandler = firstInPipeline;
        }
        else
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

Now we want to hit batch request on BatchHandler
For this we need configure route to BatchHandler
Add below code to your AppStart

```
var batchHandler = new BatchHandler(config);
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("batch", "api/batch", null, null, batchHandler);
```